# Need help to run the scenario from an existing feature file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to `Selenium`. I have a question that if I write a new scenario to the exiting feature file and generated step definitions also. How to run the specific scenario by creating a separate task in test explorer?

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Please post your relevant code.